# Sum of an array without Jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am using brackets.io to do my javascript programming and I am wondering how to sum an array.
Now I have already looked into .reduce

```
var sum = array.reduce(function(a,b){return a,b},0);
```

but this is running an error. I also thought I'd try to make my own counter...

```
function sum(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(i = 0;i <= array.length; ++i) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

But even doing this doesn't work for me either. I'm getting an error on array.length

Open for suggestions, maybe I'm just using my Arrays wrong.
Maybe I need to do more array research?

Comment: What is `array` definition? It might not be an array.

Comment: Do you understand how `reduce` works? Why do you think `a,b` would give you a sum? Why did you not include the error in your question?

Comment: `array.reduce(function(a,b) {return a + b;})`

Comment: @axlj Why? They both work just fine. One is a pre-increment, the other is a post-increment and in this case gives the same result.

Comment: What error you get in second example?

Comment: Your `for` loop is fine, except you need to use `i < array.length`. If an array has 5 elements, they are numbered 0 through 4. Also use `var i = ...` to avoid creating an unwanted global.

Comment: `[1,2,3].reduce((a,b)=>a+b)`

Comment: sounds like you're passing an Object instead of an Array

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, yes, as others have pointed out, if `array.length` is `undefined`, then you're not giving it an array. If you _do_ have an array, then you can follow the two tips I mentioned and the `for` loop should work. (You can also use `reduce`, but it's a really good idea to know the basics too.)

Answer (score 6):

Your reduce is wrong. You need to return the new value added to the accumulator (`a`).

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var sum = array.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;  
});

console.log(sum);
```

There isn't an obvious reason for the second function being incorrect (aside from `i <= array.length`, which will be out of bounds for the last increment). We would need to see what `array` is to determine the issue, but it sounds like it's not actually an array.

Another way you can write your function is such:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var count = 0;

var sum = function(num) {
  count += num;  
}

array.forEach(sum);

console.log(count);
```

I tend to use `forEach` instead of for loops when dealing with arrays. It eliminates the potential mistake of going out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Your `reduce` function isn't correct. You need to return the result of adding the two values.

```
var sum = array.reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b }, 0);
```

Comment: in case of, where the elements are primitives, you could omit the start value.

Comment: @NinaScholz you could but I think it's always a good idea to use one so you don't get unexpected errors. For instance, if array is `[]` and there is no initial value provided a TypeError would be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way that i know, if you don't like another operators and like loops so much <3:

```js
    var arr = [1, 3, 7, 19];
    
    function arrSum(arr) {
     var sum = 0;
     for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         sum += arr[i];
        }
     console.log(sum);
    }
    arrSum(arr);
```

Good luck!